# Prevent Integer.parseInt(str) from using a letter

Tags: java

im currently using Integer.parseInt(str) to convert a string to an int. How can i prevent it from converting it (and just print out unknown number) if the user inputs a letter?

```
String numberID = userChoice;
int index = Integer.parseInt(numberID) - 1;
```

Comment: You can't. Handle the exception thrown instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can not do what you are asking. Like already mentioned you do need to use a try-catch statement, this is because when .parseInt() encounters an error it raises an exception, as the programmer you can "listen" for one of these exceptions and do things if it occurs. This is done with a try catch statement. Its not a hard concept and its very well documented, I've given an example below.

```
//Must be declared outside of try block 
int index
try{
index = Integer.parseInt(numberID) - 1;
//Catches all NumberFormatExceptions but not other errors
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
//Handle error here
}
```

If you were to do this:

```
try{
    int index = Integer.parseInt(numberID) - 1;
}
```

you couldn't use index outside of the try block because it will go out of scope after the try was completed because the variable was declared within the try. Sometimes this is fine but other times it is how you want it to behave.

Answer (score 2):

[`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) will not convert an invalid input to an integer.

If you want to check that your input is a valid number, you need to catch [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html):

```
try {
    int index = Integer.parseInt(numberID) - 1;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // invalid number
}
```